# .NET CORE - Role based controller selection

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, .net-core, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a simple API which only support one role as of now.

I would like to add an admin role and a normal user. I'm using JWT to authenticate and I have a roleName in my claims.

Now, I would like to have one route for some of my endpoints, but based on what role the user logged in with, the controller corresponding to either admin or user is selected and executed.

Simple example

As a normal user:
/v1/members

returns
{
    "memberId": int,
    "name: string,
    "address": string
}

If the admin user logs in, I would like to have the same url /v1/members, but with another return

eg.

{
    "memberId": int,
    "name: string,
    "address": string,
    "socialSecurityNumber": string,
    "privatInfo": string,
    "notforuser": string
}

I know I could do it in one controller and switch out the roles, but it makes my code very messy and I don't think that's the way to do it.

Best regards from Jens

Answer (score 1):

I'm just gonna answer my own question.

After some hours researching I finally found a solution, that I think works great.
In stead of hooking into the convensions as such I define a middleware, that runs before the MVC actions. It rewrites the local url for the controller and then it hits the correct controller and it's split into separate areas. It works great.

Best regards
Jens :-)